# joomla mysql query with parameter like

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5

I want to bind the id of the content item table and link the menu table. I need to build the query as follows:

```
protected function getListQuery() 
{

    $url="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=";
    // Create a new query object.
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    // select the items
    $query->select('ar.id,ar.alias,ar.introtext,ar.images,ar.created,m.link,m.path');

    // of content table and menu table
    $query->from('#__content as ar, #__menu as m');
    $query->where('m.link like '+$url+'ar.id');

    $query->order('ar.id desc');
    return $query;
}
```

The query returns 0 results. I need to attach the `$url` parameter and `ar.id` to generate me find the full url.

What I want you to show me a list of menu items in the table are linked to the parameter.
for example:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=70
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with Concat

```
     $query->where("m.link like CONCAT('%','$url',ar.id,'%') ");
```

Comment: Are you not missing a closing bracket to end CONCAT? Might be the cause of the error

Comment: I tried with the way you put me and also replacing $url with the actual path....error 500....

Comment: prefect! the problem is in close CONCAT!.....jeje....I had not seen....Thaks!! :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Joomla, so I am only familiar with Joomla from version 3.8.6.

Your query could benefit from some well-placed quoting methods.

(For clarity, JOINs with comma-syntax are JOINs a.k.a. INNER JOINS.)

If your actual column data is fully represented by `$url` with the `ar.id` appended, then you don't need a `LIKE` string comparison function (since you are not using special characters: `_` or `%`).

- `q()` is short for `quote()` -- to be used on string values
- `qn()` is short for `quoteName()` -- to be used on column/table names

Suggested / Untested Code:

```
protected function getListQuery() 
{
    $url="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=";
    $columns = array('ar.id','ar.alias','ar.introtext','ar.images','ar.created','m.link','m.path');
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                ->select($db->qn($columns))
                ->from($db->qn('#__content', 'ar'))
                ->join('INNER', $db->qn('#__menu', 'm'))
                ->where($db->qn('m.link') . " = CONCAT('$url', " . $db->qn('ar.id') . ")")
                ->order($db->qn('ar.id') . ' DESC');
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: @user3387682 If you or anyone else finds anything wrong or suboptimal about my answer, I'd like to know 1. because I don't want to spread bad coding practices 2. I'd like to learn best practices for my own development.